# Swift - init in singleton class?

Tags: swift, singleton

I have a singleton class `MyClass` for management work with third party sdk. Inside singleton I have `init` method.

My question is : does `init` method called every time I call something from singleton like `MyClass.shared.mymethod()` or in order to call init I have to call `var instance = MyClass()` ?

Comment: You have to create a new instance of the class like you have suggested.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

### The `init` gets called only the first time you invoke `MyClass.shared`

At that point the instance of `MyClass` is saved inside the `shared` static constant.

### Example

Let's consider this Singleton class

```
final class Singleton {
    static let shared = Singleton()
    private init() {
        print("Singleton initialized")
    }

    var count = 0
}
```

Now let's look at the output into the console

[image]

As you can see the `Singleton initialized` string is printed only once. This means the init is only called once.

> **Note**: Of course I assumed the implementation of your Singleton class is correct.

Comment: Interesting, are type properties lazy by default?

Comment: you print(1,2..), instead print(Singleton.shared.count) why?

Comment: Explained well, but the printing of 1, 2, 3, 4 over the value of `count` is a little unexpected and may confuse a novice, i.e. the result of `Singleton.shared.count += 1` is unused and therefore untested/unchecked.

consider replacing it with

`print("Initial value: \(Singleton.shared.count)")`
`for _ in 0...3 {`
`Singleton.shared.count += 1`
`print(Singleton.shared.count)`
`}`
`

Comment: I found this [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/cocoa_design_patterns/managing_a_shared_resource_using_a_singleton#overview) really helpful.

Comment: This is awesome and all but if you are using reactive programming like me you may need the singleton initialize at app startup so the observers actually react.

In my case for now I just did something like `_ = ManagerName.shared` at Appdelegate.